# How can I limit WordPress editor roles to a specific category?

Tags: permissions, categories

We're trying to use WordPress as a light CMS system and we need to be able to section off parts of WordPress so that editors for one product aren't able to edit other products.

Seems like out of the box WP has 5 user levels but there isnt any thought around fine grain access (without using WP Network)

Comment: I use [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend ;)

- [Restrict categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-categories/)
- [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)

Comment: Role Scoper seems too heavy for what I want to do. Ive already explored these options. However Restrict Cats looks like a winner!

Comment: Google is indeed your friend, the problem is sometimes knowing what to look for first.